# Paired list with different delimiters

Tags: coldfusion

I have a list which I want to split out and insert into a table. The list contains paired names and values:

```
R0006^^1.00000000~~R0042^^1.00000000~~R0049^^1.00000000~~R0072^^1.00000000~~R0088^^3.00000000~~R0092^^1.00000000~~R0106^^1.00000000
```

How can I loop over this list and insert the names and values into a database table as I am struggling to get in my head the use of different delimiters and their associated values.

Many Thanks
JC

Comment: How about `ListToArray(myVar, "~~")` ?

Comment: You can also use cfloop with a delimiter to loop over your list.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

ColdFusion's tags & functions don't fully deal with multi-character delimiters very well. `ArrayToList()` supports multiple delimiters but most most other list-related functions do not.

If your data never contains a `~` or `^` by itself, I would take advantage of that and replace the 2-length delimiters with one-length delmiters.

(Edit: As Leigh points out in comments, a `ReReplace`, or `ReplaceList()` is not needed in this case as CF ignores empty elements by default). It won't change the output to remove it, but that's the point, having it there isn't doing anything useful either. Commented out for clarity of point.)

```
<cfset dList = "R0006^^1.00000000~~R0042^^1.00000000~~R0049^^1.00000000~~R0072^^1.00000000~~R0088^^3.00000000~~R0092^^1.00000000~~R0106^^1.00000000" />
<!---cfset dList = ReReplace(dList,"(~|\^)\1","\1","ALL")--->
<cfset dArray = ListToArray(dList,"~",false) />
<cfloop array="#dArray#" index="a1">
  <cfquery...>
    insert into mytable(lname,lvalue)
    values(<cfqueryparam value="#listfirst(a1,"^")#">,<cfqueryparam value="#listlast(a1,"^^")#">)
  </cfquery>
</cfloop>
```

The nice part about this is that it has pretty good backwards compatibility as well.

However, this does assume that each item in the `~` delimited list has two sub-items. If it does not, and only has the field label, you can do this.

```
<cfset dList = "R0006^^1.00000000~~R0042^^1.00000000~~R0049^^1.00000000~~R0072^^1.00000000~~R0088^^3.00000000~~R0092^^1.00000000~~R0106^^1.00000000" />
<!---cfset dList = ReReplace(dList,"(~|\^)\1","\1","ALL")--->
<cfset dArray = ListToArray(dList,"~",false) />
<cfloop array="#dArray#" index="a1">
  <cfquery...>
    insert into mytable(lname,lvalue)
    values(<cfqueryparam value="#listfirst(a1,"^")#">,<cfqueryparam value="#(listlen(a1,"^") gt 1 ? listlast(a1,"^") : "")#">)
  </cfquery>
</cfloop>
```

Finally, as David Faber points out in the comments, you can use `ReplaceList(dlist, "~~,^^", "~,^")` instead of `ReReplace(dList,"(~|\^){2}","\1","ALL")` which will achieve the same goal but has the added benefit of being easier to read for people who may not be comfortable with Regular Expressions.

Comment: The only thing I might do different is to use `replaceList()` instead of `ReReplace()`: `replaceList(dlist, "~~,^^", "~,^")`

Comment: For folks uncomfortable with regex especially, that's a great idea! @DavidFaber

Comment: Many thanks for this great answer @cfqueryparam. Great detail in your answer that has helped me out a lot.

Comment: @cfqueryparam, actually I was thinking that regex is an expensive way to do this. Then I thought that your regex isn't quite right because it will match `~^` and `^~` -- you would want something like `ReReplace(dList,"(~|\^)\1","\1","ALL")` -- but then, if those sequences are present the whole solution won't work anyway.

Comment: @DavidFaber You know, I was thinking about that last night and wondering how I had written the strMatch part of the `ReReplace()`, but it was too late to dig out the computer. Still, thanks for the catch. (Also I didn't mean to imply that you were uncomfortable with regex fyi)

Comment: @cfqueryparam, I didn't take it that way :)

Comment: @cfqueryparam - What is the point of the regex's here? Seems like an over complication if you are ultimately just going to use a list loop. Since the delimiter consists of repeated characters, cfloop would *essentially* ignore the extra character anyway.  ie  It should yield the same result as a simple `<cfloop delimiter="~" index="pair" list="#theString#"...>` and `listFirst(pair, "^")` and `listRest(pair, "^")`.  Though as David mentioned above, all bets are off if the list elements contain either of those characters..

Comment: @JeepersCreepers As Leigh points out, the `ReReplace()` is not needed and can be removed from the code. With the third parameter of `ListToArray()` set to false, empty elements are ignored.

Comment: Leigh That's a valid point with the third parameter of `ArrayToList()` set to false (or not set, since false is default), the elements aren't even loaded into the array at all. The Replace, of any type, is really without use.

Comment: (Edit) Technically, they could do without the array too. In some cases, arrays are better, but in this case it is a bit redundant. It will not not hurt, but a simple cfloop list and two (2) list functions would do it.

Answer (score 1):

I would take a slightly different approach (for the reasons stated in my comments ... what if the character sequences `~^` or `^~` exist in the data, or even the single characters `^` or `~`?) and turn the list into JSON, then deserialize it into a struct:

```
<cfset the_list = "R0006^^1.00000000~~R0042^^1.00000000~~R0049^^1.00000000~~R0072^^1.00000000~~R0088^^3.00000000~~R0092^^1.00000000~~R0106^^1.00000000" />

<!--- Escape characters that need to be escaped --->
<cfset the_list = replace(the_list, "\", "\\", "all") />
<cfset the_list = replace(the_list, """", "\""", "all") />

<cfset the_list = replace(the_list, "^^", """:""", "all") />
<cfset the_list = "{""" & replace(the_list, "~~", """,""", "all") & """}" />

<cfset the_coll = deserializeJSON(the_list) />
```

The only difficulty with the above would be if there were duplicate keys. In that case one might use an array of structs - this can be accomplished simply by changing the line replacing the double tilde `~~`:

```
<cfset the_list = "[{""" & replace(the_list, "~~", """},{""", "all") & """}]" />
```

Then loop over the array to insert into the database.